# AsyncTask not call doInBackground methods

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Here is my code:

```
new Loading.LoadTast(ctx) {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
                Looper.prepare();
                String msg=changePwd();
                closeProgressDialog();
                if(msg == null) {
                    SmartNgApplication.getInstance().exit();
                } else {
                    BaseHelper.showToast(ctx, msg);
                }
                Looper.loop();
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();


public abstract static class LoadTast extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private Context ctx;

    public LoadTast(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx=ctx;
    }

    protected abstract String doInBackground(Integer... params);

    public void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(ctx, "", "loading...", true, false);
    }

    public void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        BaseHelper.showToast(ctx, result);
    }
}
```

Click the button to run the method. Clicking it 5 times `AsyncTask.onPreExecute` is called but not call `doInBackground` so the screen still show a dialog.

I think have something wrong for `AsyncTask` `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`

Comment: Why is it so important to overwrite the `doInBackground()` method? Why not have it inside the `AsyncTask`?

Comment: because new Loading.LoadTast(ctx) called in many Class and i don't want to write onPreExecute method every Class

Comment: You don't have to? Once you create your class, then all you need to do is call `new LoadTast.execute([int params]);` Also, you need to declare what variables are going to be used by your `AsyncTask`, eg `public abstract static class LoadTast extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {`

Comment: sorry in my code has "<" i replace with "& lt ;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should not call any UI changing methods in doInBackground. Thats what onPostExecute is there for. Do only whats not allowed on the UI thread in doInBackground.
2. To check why doInBackground is not called, please try putting the implementation (from the anonymous inner class) into LoadTast just too see if it is called then.
3. I have implemented an AsyncWrapper by having subclasses call renamed onPostExecute and doInBackground. It should be possible to overwrite the wrapped Methods in an anonymous inner class like the one you are using in your example.

This is the short version. My real code involves some genral exception handling not only the call to the wrapped methods.

```
public abstract class AsyncTaskWrapper<Params, Progress, Result> 
  extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {

  @Override
  final protected Result doInBackground(Params... params) {
    return wrappedDoInBackground(params);
  }

  protected abstract Result wrappedDoInBackground(Params... params);

  protected abstract void wrappedOnPostExecute(Result result);

  final protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {

    wrappedOnPostExecute(result);
  }

}
```

Comment: Amen. See this blogpost for more information on AsyncTask http://blogactivity.wordpress.com/2011/09/01/proper-use-of-asynctask/

Answer (score 1):

As Todd Sjolander said in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839384/asynctask-doinbackground-not-called-in-android-tablet) ...

> The multi-threading model changed between 2.3.5 and 4.0.4. AsyncTask
>   now defaults to having all subclasses in an application using the same
>   thread (i.e. only one AsyncTask can run at a time!). It's explained
>   here:
>
> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single
>   background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of
>   threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with
>   HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common
>   application errors caused by parallel execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke
>   executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with
>   THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.
>
> With that in mind, it could be that another AsyncTask is running in
>   your app, thereby preventing this one from ever starting. That would
>   explain why it works fine on your 2.3.5 device, but not your 4.0.4
>   tablet.