# Start Two AsyncTasks for parallel Computing and continue when they've finished

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have to edit huge bitmap files, so I want to use all cores of my device to speed up the process. I thought it would be a good solution to:

- Count the number of available cores
- Split the image into [numberofcores] parts
- For each core create a new thread and let this thread handle one part of the image

How do I make sure all threads are done before I continue with other tasks, like saving the picture or return a message that the bitmap has been processed completely?

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but I wouldn't recommend using `AsyncTask`.  Depending on the Android version, it may not run those tasks in parallel.  I explain that a bit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839384/asynctask-doinbackground-not-called-in-android-tablet/12865486#12865486)

Comment: so no asynctask but simple threads? May I call them from the UI-Thread or do I have to call these threads by an AsyncTask?

Comment: The main issue is that you can't update the UI in any way from any thread but the UI thread.  To get the non-UI threads to update the UI, you can pass the threads a `Handler`, then have the thread run `Handler.post()`, and pass it a `Runnable` like this: `myHandler.post(new Runnable() { public void run() { //Do UI code here } });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should make another `AsyncTask` that waits for all the other threads to complete, so in the `doInBackground()` method of your waiting `AsyncTask` you can do the following :

```
while( task1.getStatus()!=AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED
         || task1.getStatus()!= AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
    Thread.sleep(500);
}
```

and then in the `onPostExecute()` method of your "waiting task" you can continue with the other tasks.

Comment: yeah, you could do the same. `Asynctask` is basically just a helper task wrapped around a `Thread`.

Answer (score 1):

[Join](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) each worker thread after you've started all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Extend a `Handler.Callback` class with an array that keeps track of threads processing a particular image (might need to extend `Thread` too, so that you can specify what portion of the `Bitmap` the particular thread is processing), a the end of each threads processing `sendMessage` to a `Handler` object you create with your extended class instance.

Override `handleMessage` in the extended class, to receive result of particular thread remove thread from processing array store results of particular thread. When processing array size is 0, put results together.