# Android Regarding download data and list in fragment

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-listfragment

I am a bit confuse with the new fragment on on API 15 and above. I had been developing on old API 10 the gingerbread version. The method I used on getting the data I want by using `AsyncTask` to download the data on main activity and stored it into internal storage then use another `AsyncTask` to populate my listview.

Now I decided to build a new app by starting with API 15 Master Detail Flow, it start with Fragment Activity and Fragment which is kinda cool for phone and tablet. So my question is by using the old method `AsyncTask` will it still be feasible or it is recommended to use other method for downloading data and populating the listview??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended to use a Loader for populating the list view.

You can have your ListActivity implement `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<E>`

You will get three method to override: onLoaderCreate, onLoaderFinish, onLoaderReset.

In onLoaderCreate is where you tell it what object you want the Loader to load. In case of a cursor, you could create a cursorLoader Object, that will return you a Cursor object when you finish loading (onLoaderFinish). Then you could use the cursor to populate your adapter for the listView.

As for the Asyn for downloading. You could implement an IntentService. You can run it by:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, IntentService.class);
startService(intent);
```

You can get call back from this background service by using a broadcase Receiver.

Comment: About intentservice, I know it can show the progress on the notification bar, but if I wanted to only show the progress only inside the app lets say on Actionbar can it be done? I am not doing heavy download on the app, just a list of string.

Comment: Yes it is easy to be done, here is a tut on how: [link](http://android-er.blogspot.ca/2013/03/generate-notification-in-intentservice.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's always recommended for any version of API to use separate thread (in this case AsyncTask doInBackground method) for the long running tasks such as downloading data from the internet.

Comment: The data I will be downloading is in small file size only,
I still thinking of using AsyncTask doInBackground in my FragmentActivity for downloading, so I can easily put up progress bar on the Actionbar. So is fine right?

Comment: Exactly you may use onPreExecute() method of AsyncTask class to display the progress dialog. if you have long time downloading you might consider using the service.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to spin off slow tasks on their own threads.  Beware of `AsyncTask`, though, because depending on the OS version and your own settings, you may not be able to run more than one `AsyncTask` at a time.  See my other answer and comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12865486/1029773)

Comment: Well one AsyncTask will be run one at a time, thanks for the notice.