# Client listen to server messages

Tags: java, android, client-server

I have a client-server program in java.. I need to handle in 2 scenarios:

1. The client send messages to the server and the server processes
   the message and return the        result. (this works fine)
2. When something happens at the server I need to send the data to
   the client to process it.

To be more specific on the second scenario, I'm trying to develop an android app, so when 
I'm getting a text messages (SMS) it sends to my PC the sender data and the message body. I'm doing this by using the WIFI network (just for fun :) )

Any ideas? I thought about to have a thread in my client side (PC) to listen the server messages.. but I don't think its a good solution..

Comment: You need to look up socket connections and how Java handles them. Good start here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/

Answer (score 1):

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=22

A good place to start and indeed a client thread is a possible solution.

You can also check with node.js non blocking client server interactions. http://blog.smsified.com/tag/node-js/

Answer (score 0):

You need a asynctask to handle the incoming data and to create the socket on its own

I had did something very like what your trying to and this is what solved my problem

[My Solution to my own Problem and it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226068/asynctask-doinbackground-never-runs-in-android)

And the same needs to happen on your server just make sure not to close the sockets